# How do I let my Java apps interact with my console C# apps?

Tags: c#, java, console, msmq

I want to create a C# console application in which my other Java console apps in other machines can query how much messages are in MSMQ.

I'm wondering, how do can I implement that? In what way will they be able to communicate? What's the standard way that most people do this?

Comment: Maybe you can be even more specific on where is your problem. Just saying Java apps is way to general to get any real help.

Comment: You can use self hosted WCF server and RESTful approach. Here is a small but working example. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13166299/932418

Comment: Is this also your question but posted under a different name? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438154/whats-the-recommended-way-for-console-applications-to-talk-with-each-other

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually you already have half the job done with your queue, it all depends on your scenario, but if you want to send messages from one application to another (regardless of the language on which it was built):

- it could be by means of a queue, so having a client for the same queue platform will get you going,
- another approach is to use wcf services that provide you with more interoperability than tipical web services,
- finally there are new technologies out there (in .net is OData), that let you build a RESTful approach, so you can query information in the same way you navigate in a website, so for example: (http://myapplication/users/?id=4) , then any client application (java or c#) can consume it with their own implementation of REST clients.

I'm quite sure there are are many other ways, but this are the ones I have tried already.

Hope it helps.